# Normalization of Data - Basic Absorbance Data and Multiple Treatments

Tags: normalization

[image]

Information for the columns below
1. No treatment, just cells in media. + Absorbance Reader
2. Treated with PEI + Absorbance Reader
3. Treated with Triton + Absorbance Reader
4. Treated with silica + Absorbance Reader
5. Treated with PLA + Absorbance Reader
6. Positive Control - Contains NO CELLS, just media + Absorbance Reader
7. Negative Control -  Contains NO CELLS, just media + Half Absorbance Reader/Half water

The specifics are irrelevant. My main question is how would I normalize data sets from this.

Would I divide each cell by the overall highest absorption or divide each column by the highest absorption in that column.

Comment: Why do you want to normalize these data? If you’re comparing results of the different treatments you can just use them as they stand.

Comment: I got the answer.

Comment: First the two controls on the right had to be subtracted from the overall absorbance. Then you had to divide everything by the control on the far left to get a relative value.